# Find Index of Column(s) after it has been Moved

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

We are using DHTMLX Grid. Need some help, please.

I have a table and each columns (has filter/dropdown) are allocated an id eg. fac, date, sel, loc, tag ... etc

We have hard coded the index of columns to set and get the cookie elsewhere.

```
    function doInitGrid(){  

mygrid.setColumnIds("fac,date,sel,loc,tag");  //set ids   
mygrid.attachEvent("onFilterStart",function(ind,data)
                            {
setCookie("Tray_fac_filter",mygrid.getFilterElement(0).value,365); //column index 0
setCookie("Tray_loc_filter",mygrid.getFilterElement(3).value,365);//column index 3
setCookie("Tray_tag_filter",mygrid.getFilterElement(4).value,365); //column index 4

mygrid.getFilterElement(0).value = getCookie("Tray_fac_filter")
mygrid.getFilterElement(3).value = getCookie("Tray_dep_filter")
mygrid.getFilterElement(4).value = getCookie("Tray_prg_filter")
});
}
```

But when the columns are moved, the problem arises as the index of the column changes yet it is set in setCookie /getCoookie

DHTMLX allows to get the index of the id using --

```
var colInd = grid.getColIndexById(id); 
eg: var  colInd = grid.getColIndexById(date); // outputs 1.
After moving the date column to the end -- fac, sel, loc, tag, date // it will output 4.
```

However, we have about 14 columns that can be moved/rearranged and I could use the

```
var colInd = grid.getColIndexById(id); 15 times

var facInd = grid.getColIndexById("fac");
var dateInd = grid.getColIndexById("date");
var selInd = grid.getColIndexById("sel");
var locInd = grid.getColIndexById("loc";
var tagInd = grid.getColIndexById("tag");
```

and put those variables in the set/get cookie. I was thinking if there was a better way.

To understand the code better, I have put the minimised version of the code in fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/19eggs/s5myW/2/

Answer (score 0):

You've got the best answer I think.  Do it in a loop and it's easier:

```
var cookie_prefix = "Fray_filter_";
var cookie_dur = 365;
var num_cols = dhx_grid.getColumnCount();

// filter vals to cookies
for (var col_idx=0; col_idx<num_cols; col_idx++) {
  var filter = mygrid.getFilterElement(col_idx)
  if (filter) { // not all columns may have a filter
    var col_id = dhx_grid.getColumnId(col_idx);
    var cookie_name = cookie_prefix+col_id;
    setCookie(cookie_name, filter.value, cookie_dur);
  }
}

// cookies to filter vals
for (var col_idx=0; col_idx<num_cols; col_idx++) {
    var col_id = dhx_grid.getColumnId(col_idx);
  var filter_val = getCookie(cookie_prefix+col_id);
  var filter = mygrid.getFilterElement(col_idx)
  filter.value = filter_val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dhtmlxgrid native event to assign the correct id everytime a column is moved.
The event is called onAfterCMove, you can check the documentation here. [onAfterCMove Event](http://docs.dhtmlx.com/doku.php?id=dhtmlxgrid%3aevent_onbeforecmove_onaftermove)

You would do something like:

```
mygrid.attachEvent('onAfterCMove',function(cInd,posInd){
 //Your processing here to change the cookies; where cInd is the index of the column moved 
 //and posInd, is the position where it Was moved
}):
```